# win.close() also closes message box in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4.1

I have a textbox. As soon as user types something, I open a window and show the data in the window. If no result is found, I want to close this window and then show a message box. Please see below image for more information.
[image]

On the load event of the store I have written following code.

```
'load': function (thisStore, records, successful, eOpts) {
            if (successful) {
                if (records == null || typeof records[0] === "undefined") {

                    var msg = 'No records found for the given selection.';
                    MessageWindow.show('Information', msg, Ext.Msg.OK, Ext.Msg.INFO);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Now to close the search result window, I have changed the code to:**

```
'load': function (thisStore, records, successful, eOpts) {
            if (successful) {
                if (records == null || typeof records[0] === "undefined") {
                      var win = Ext.WindowManager.getActive();
                        if (win) {
                            win.close();
                        }
                    var msg = 'No records found for the given selection.';
                    MessageWindow.show('Information', msg, Ext.Msg.OK, Ext.Msg.INFO);
                }
            }
        }
```

But when this code executes, it also closes message box (along with search window). I just want to close the search window.

Please helo

Answer (score 1):

First is, that the messagebox ( as explained by  Evan Trimboli ) is no child of the window.

I've testes this behavior on my local extjs project( creating an Ext.Window, and then creating an messagebox ). Heres some code

```
    openWindow: function() {
    this.initWindow();
    this.window.doLayout();
    this.window.show();

    Ext.MessageBox.alert( translate('error', 'general'), 'tag' );
    window.setTimeout(function() {                 
        BlueFork.Taskstatus.Creation.window.close();
        BlueFork.Taskstatus.Creation.window.destroy();
    }, 5000);
},
```

using this code, extjs will close the window and not the messagebox.

using

```
var win = Ext.WindowManager.getActive();
win.close();
```

will close the messagebox.

have you already debugged how often your load event is triggert?

Maybe its triggerd twice, first getActive returns the messagebox, second trigger, returns the window? both windows are getting closed.

cheers!

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that its possible to just close the window while retaining the message box. What you can do is once the window is closed, display a new message box with the same text.

Comment: -1 This isn't correct, the message box is in no way a child of the other window.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. if you see the code, I am first closing the window and then showing the message. I am not sure why it closes both window and message box.